# using `sub()` function in awk cause repetitive replacement behavior

Tags: awk

Suppose I have this `/etc/crontab` file example:

```
0 0 1 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org && hwclock -w
```

What I want to achieve is to replace this line with another `ntpdate` cronjob like the following

```
0 0 0 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org && hwclock -w
```

And if the original `ntpdate` line doesn't exist, then the second line just get appended at the end of the `crontab` file.

Therefore, I tried it with `awk`:

```
awk -v cronjob='0 0 0 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org && hwclock -w' '/ntpdate/ { sub(/^.*$/,cronjob,$0);found=1; }; { print $0 }; END {if(!found) print cronjob}' /etc/crontab
```

which leads to the following (certainly wrong) repetitive replacement:

```
0 0 0 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org 0 0 1 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org && hwclock -w0 0 1 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org && hwclock -w hwclock -w
```

What is wrong with my `awk` script? I must have misunderstood something, but I cannot figure out where.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `&` is a metacharacter in replacement strings; it means 'whatever you matched'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, yeah, I get it... I wasn't aware of the  `&&` part of `cronjob` variable caused the chaos... Thank you. Would you mind phrase your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Will do...just working out the fix, too...

Comment: I just escaped the `&` like so `\&`, and it worked...

Comment: Hmm...interesting...that's what I expected, too, but on my Mac (with both BSD `awk` and GNU `awk`), I seem to need `\\&\\&` with doubled backslashes.

Comment: I'm using the default version shipped with Ubuntu, by `awk -W version` I get this version info: `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996`

Comment: you may use `awk '/ntpdate/{$3=0} /etc/crontab'` in this case. For more general cases you can simply remove the matched line and append the new one. This way you can have the same effect while avoiding substitution and the `found` variable.

Comment: @pii_ke: I think your suggestion is eminently sensible.

Comment: @pii_ke In my real problem, my cronjob specs are variable based on certain conditions. Thus a simple `{$3=0}` would not work. However, your suggestion for the general cases is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Succinctly, `&` is a metacharacter in replacement strings; it means 'whatever you matched'.  That's why you're getting the repetition.

The next issue is "how to avoid it".  The answer seems to be two pairs of backslashes:

```
awk -v cronjob='0 0 0 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org \\&\\& hwclock -w' \
    '/ntpdate/ { sub(/^.*$/,cronjob,$0); found=1; } { print $0 }
     END {if(!found) print cronjob}'
```

I was expecting a single backslash to be sufficient, but with my testing (using both BSD `awk` and GNU `awk` on Mac OS X 10.10.4), it seemed I needed a double backslash.  My expectation ties in with [Naitree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1602266/naitree)'s [experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216043/using-sub-function-in-awk-cause-repetitive-replacement-behavior#comment50433015_31216043) — but I'm not sure why I needed the the extra backslashes and he didn't.  In the interim, take whichever of the options works for you: try single backslashes, and if it works, great, and if not, try double backslashes instead.

When I tried this on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM, then I found that `awk` was indeed `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996`, and the single backslash was sufficient.  Ouch! My suspicion is that BSD `awk` and GNU `awk` hew closer to the POSIX standard in this than `mawk` does, if only because they're a decade or so newer (for me, `awk --version` for BSD `awk` yields `awk version 20070501`, while `gawk --version` yields `GNU Awk 3.1.7` and an end copyright date of 2009).

With the single `\&`, `gawk` reports:

```
gawk -v cronjob='0 0 0 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org \&\& hwclock -w' \
     '/ntpdate/ { sub(/^.*$/,cronjob,$0);found=1; } { print $0 }
      END {if(!found) print cronjob}' /dev/null
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\&' treated as plain `&'
0 0 0 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org && hwclock -w
```

Note the warning.   It appeared on both Ubuntu and Mac OS X.
 That's the 'addition' mode; `/dev/null` doesn't contain a match for the line.  If you save that in file `x1` and then edit `x1` with the same command line apart from the file name, I got the original repeated behaviour:

```
0 0 0 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org 0 0 0 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org && hwclock -w0 0 0 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org && hwclock -w hwclock -w
```

#### Alternatively

As [pii_ke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1921546/pii-ke) suggests in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216043/using-sub-function-in-awk-cause-repetitive-replacement-behavior/31216123#comment50433097_31216043), a simpler technique is probably:

```
awk -v cronjob='0 0 0 * * ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org && hwclock -w' \
    '/ntpdate/ { next } { print $0 } END {print cronjob}'
```

This deletes the original line and simply adds the new one at the end of the output.  This worked sanely with all three variants of `awk`.

**YMMV** — Your mileage may vary; you were warned.  These horribly subtle differences are the sort of thing that can drive you insane if you don't simply evade the problem.